# Eclipse Mars: Unhandled event loop exception in OCaml

Tags: java, eclipse, ocaml, unhandled-exception

I am using Eclipse for programming in Java and OCaml. I have just installed OCaml in Eclipse and it worked for like 5 minutes and then I get `"Unhandled event loop exception"` error. I searched a lot of forums and looked for answers but I can't solve this problem. Java is working correctly, but OCaml not. I tried to modify the plugins, the SWT, I closed all the nVidia tasks but none of these solutions worked for me. Does somebody know what to do?

[Here is the whole message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9oP6.jpg)

```
Stacktrace of the message:
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:507)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.access$0(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1266)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1137)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1122)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1164)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmKeyDown(Widget.java:1883)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_KEYDOWN(Control.java:5049)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_KEYDOWN(Canvas.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4708)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5050)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2549)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3767)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ocaml.editor.actions.ToplevelQuickEvalAction.run(ToplevelQuickEvalAction.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.ActionDelegateHandlerProxy.execute(ActionDelegateHandlerProxy.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    ... 50 more
```

Comment: You should probably add 'ocaml' tag to your question, I have major doubts that anybody looking at java or eclipse tags has much experience with it...

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message

Comment: I posted screenshot of the whole message.

Comment: I've never worked in this environment. But one thing I see is that OCaml is telling you some paths aren't correctly set. Maybe the path to the compiler needs to be specified.

Comment: You can doubleclick the error message to see the stacktrace.

Comment: I think that all the paths are correctly set because I set them just like in the tutorial.

Comment: I posted the stacktrace.